# DotNetCore Capture A Screenshot in Windows

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am looking to capture a screenshot using .NET core. I know that this is trivial using the .NET framework but is this possible using .NET core? I have searched but I can't find any answers anywhere.

Comment: I don't think that Dot Net Core has a way of taking screenshots. But you could potentially call into a screenshotting class library using .NET Framework from 
a .NET Core application.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`System.Drawing.Common` is available in .NET Core now allowing you to take screenshots of windows/your desktop. [Here is an example](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoYouUseSystemDrawingInNETCore.aspx)

**EDIT**

An example capturing a screenshot:

```cs
using var bitmap = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0,
    bitmap.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
}
bitmap.Save("filename.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

**UPDATE**

`System.Drawing.Common` has been deprecated on iOS and Linux but is still maintained for Windows. [See related article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only).

Comment: The linked example does not take a screenshot. It only resizes an image from file.

Comment: The question relates to taking a screenshot, but this answer does not include taking a screenshot

Comment: @GregTrevellick Yes it does. The copy from screen with the given values will take a screenshot of your desktop within those bounds. It then inserts that captured image into the Bitmap object and saves it to the given file.

Comment: Double checked the values from my demo. The `CopyFromScreen` initial two parameters should be 0 for a full screen capture. Updated the answer

Comment: My bad, apologies, I should have read it thoroughly - but at least now I know and can hopefully use this answer.

Comment: No problem. Please let me know if you have any issues with it

Comment: It works, but not how i was hoping.. i have 2 screens and just captures one screen

Comment: @CHIRINGUCHI have you tried modifying the Bitmap constructor values to the combined x value of your resolution?

Comment: @Tubs in my case, my project was a Library Code Project, I Created a Windows Forms Proyect and it worked

Comment: As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only System.Drawing.Common is no longer supported for any .NET core version. Thank you

Comment: It is supported for Windows but you're right about iOS and Linux

Answer (score 4):

.net core is a cross-platform framework, which means it may run on various platforms, even those not having a screen at all (embedded Linux, for instance).
Therefore you cannot do it directly from a .net core library.
What you *can* do is implement platform-specific screenshot grabbing in libraries of respective types: win, android, mac, etc. and connect it to the facilities of you cross-platform code over a DI-container, for example.