# Determine screen size with .NET Core 5?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-5

How to determine the screen size with .NET Core? I want to take a screenshot as described in [DotNetCore Capture A Screenshot in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173336/dotnetcore-capture-a-screenshot-in-windows/50173501) but they use a fixed 1920*1080 resolution which does not work for my purposes.

Do I have to reference System.Windows.Forms and thereby being nailed down to Windows?

Before switching to .NET Core we used System.Windows.Forms like so:

```
new Size
{
  Width = Screen.AllScreens.Sum(s => s.Bounds.Width),
  Height = Screen.AllScreens.Max(s => s.Bounds.Height)
}
```

Which is something we could use again, but we would love something platform-independent of course.

Comment: While the System.Drawing is available cross-platform, I wouldn't be surprised if CopyFromScreen wasn't working on linux. I'd test that first to make sure you're not trying something that requires System.Windows.Forms in the end again.

Comment: This is an open [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/22948). At present, there is no support for `Screen` info, since the platform in question may not even have a screen.

Comment: What you ask is definitely *not* platform-independent.  A web app has no screen. Mac windowing concepts and APIs are very different from Windows. Same for Linux, Android, iOS. There are some attempts to create a cross-platform GUI stack, like Xamarin Forms or the Uno Platform

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comments hint that it is not supported yet.

So I show you what we have done to implement it using Windows Forms (took me some time to understand how to reference Windows Forms in a .NET Core library project correctly):

You can add the Windows Forms dependency like so to the csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then you can use the `Screen` class again:

```
new Size
{
  Width = Screen.AllScreens.Sum(s => s.Bounds.Width),
  Height = Screen.AllScreens.Max(s => s.Bounds.Height)
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** This works on Windows only, but at least it is .NET Core compatible.

Comment: It will probably use WinApi under the hood, so it will not work on other platforms I guess, sorry don't have one under my hand rn, so can't confirm/deny that.

Comment: It uses [Winuser.h's `EnumDisplayMonitors` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaymonitors), so don't think this will answer your question.

Comment: Yep, Windows.Forms in general is only available on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For WPF solution we just used method for maximize window, take values of Width and Height of window, then return window in normal state. Also can be done with dummy second transparent window (use WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner). Take taskbar in account which is not measured.